# How can I supplement my data based on known data?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, data-analysis

I now have 2500 pieces of data. It is about the A/B/C/D properties of 2500 objects, I now want to supplement the E/F/G properties of these objects in this excel table, E/F/G can be searched on the Internet, but how to import this into excel in batches? Can I only search one by one?

| Make | Variant | Length (ft) | Geographic Region | Country/Region/State | Listing Price (USD) | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alubat Ovni | 395 | 41 | Europe | France | $267,233 | 2005 |
| Bavaria | 38 Cruiser | 38 | Europe | Croatia | $75,178 | 2005 |
| Bavaria | 38 Cruiser | 38 | Europe | Croatia | $66,825 | 2005 |
| Bavaria | 38 Cruiser | 38 | Europe | Croatia | $54,661 | 2005 |

I mean I have an excel table like this. It is about information of Sailboat Prices. To forecast the prices, I need to know more information of the sailboat (such as beam, draft, displacement, rigging, sail area, hull materials, engine hours, sleeping capacity, headroom, electronics, etc.) I could get these values on the website, but I had to fill them out manually into the form, one by one. That is too slow.

I am afraid I can only search of them one by one. I hope there is a more convenient way.

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: From your post, It is hard to tell what you are trying to achieve. Can you give us an example, please?